# How can I filter by "updated this month" in a view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a view filled with content of stuff that needs to be done every month.
I already have it set up to show everything that fits that parameter, I have one more thing i want it to filter by:
I want it to be able to show only things that have **not** been edited in the current month. This does not mean within a month. 
If today is June 02 I want to

- see something that was updated may 31
- not something edited june 01

I am able to set it by an exact day, but i don't want to have to change that every month.
I am able to set it by a set amount of time(-1 month), but this will do it within *a* month instead of within *the* month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your filter and add a contextual filter: `Content: Updated month - Date in the form of MM (01 - 12).` & select the option **Provide default value** to `Current Date`. This will make sure your view gets content from the current month & not from within a month range.

Comment: and how would the reverse be done? i forgot the not in " have not been edited"